# How to convert bytes of image to string whithout ang change in data

Tags: c#, byte

I stored my image data in a binary field in sql server
and now I need to convert my byte[] data to string

I used

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);  
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis").GetString(data); 
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("euc-jp").GetString(data);    
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);   
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

and also Convert.ToBase64String

but they encode my data

how can  I convert my data byte[] to string whitout any change?

thanks

Comment: System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data); this should be the correct charset. How did you check if your data was changed.

Comment: "Convert" and "change" are pretty much synonymous. You can't convert something without changing it in some way. You should give more details on what exactly you're trying to do. http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=convert

Comment: i just want to have a string witch included combination of my byte[] array . as an example my byte[] b = b(0)= 112, b(1)=116 , b(2)=220 my string should be like this "112116220"

Comment: I need to use this src="data:image/png;base64,bytes of image" in my web application , for it last part I need to have my byte az string .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you got something wrong here.

> I need to use this src="data:image/png;base64,bytes of image"

It says that the data should be base64 encoded so `Convert.ToBase64String` is what you want in this case.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give an answer since it's not clear what you need this for.

What you're seeing may not necessarily be an encoding problem. If you're working with image data, your byte array is bound to contain some nulls. Consider the following example:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { 65, 0, 66 };
string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

This yields the output `A` instead of three characters as you might expect, because character 2 is a null character. But three characters are indeed stored in the string, since mouse-hovering over `s` in line three above yields a Tooltip `"A\0B"`. So maybe your comparison is doing something wrong, @Damokles already asked what exactly you're doing in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

Encode your byte[] as Base64. Base64 is used to represent binary data as ASCII string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx